# getTermFreqVector() - NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lucene, tf-idf

I am trying to get the tf of a set of documents using the following code:

```
IndexReader r = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("index")));

TermFreqVector tfv = r.getTermFreqVector(root[i],"contents"); // where root[] contains the
document IDs of the documents in my corpus
```

I keep getting a null pointer exception. Can anyone please tell me what might be wrong here?
I am using Lucene 3.6.2, is there anyway to ensure that termFreqVector is enabled while indexing?

Comment: Please include a stack trace for errors. Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to check that r and root aren't null?

Comment: make sure that the termfreqvector info is enabled while indexing. You may check that using Luke or indexing sourcecode

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?  Running into the same problem myself.  I'm pretty sure I have term vectors properly indexed, but I'm seeing a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, the field `contents` is a TextField which is indexed and tokenized but without term vectors. Hence you are getting a null value. One would need more information to debug the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

Adding field into index, you should specify fourth argument like this:

doc.Add(new Field("text", text, Field.Store.NO, 
Field.Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.YES));